# Can this Kotlin casting code be simplified?

Tags: generics, kotlin

We have some code to a third party SDK that returns an "Any?".  And we have to cast it (if it casts and parse it).  Because our casts are generic, I have not been able to figure out how to simplify this without writing 5 casts.  This seems much easier in Swift. Is there a better way of doing these casts?

```
private fun parseOrganizations(payload: Any?): List<UserOrganization> {
        val organizations = mutableListOf<UserOrganization>()
        payload?.let { userData ->
            if (userData is Map<*, *>) {
                val orgJsonList = userData["organizations"]
                if (orgJsonList is List<*>) {
                    for (jsonMap in orgJsonList) {
                        if (jsonMap is Map<*, *>) {
                            val id = jsonMap["id"] as? String
                            val name = jsonMap["name"] as? String
                            val role = jsonMap["role"] as? String
                            val isActive = jsonMap["isActive"] as? Boolean
                            val isVerified = jsonMap["isVerified"] as? Boolean
                            if (id != null && name != null && role != null && isActive != null && isVerified != null) {
                                val org = UserOrganization(id, name, role, isActive, isVerified)
                                organizations.add(org)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return organizations
    }
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid a lot of nested `if` just changing it to `?.let` and `for` to `map` . Code in this case will be flat and readable

```
fun parseOrganizations(payload: Any?) {
    payload
        ?.let { it as? Map<*, *> }
        ?.let { it["organizations"] as? List<*> }
        ?.mapNotNull { if (it is Map<*, *>) UserOrganization.fromMap(it) else null }
        ?.map { organizations.add(it) }
}
```

But we should deal with creating `UserOrganization` from `Map` contains organization's details. To be honest, I could not figure out a really elegant way. But it is better to create external function or something like this, to encapsulate fallback logic:

```
class UserOrganization(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val role: String,
    val isActive: Boolean,
    val isVerified: Boolean
){
    companion object {
        fun fromMap(org: Map<*,*>): UserOrganization? =
            if (org.keys.containsAll(listOf("id", "name", "role", "isActive", "isVerified"))) {
                UserOrganization(
                    id = org["id"] as? String ?: "Unknown Id",
                    name = org["name"] as? String ?: "Unknown name",
                    role = org["role"] as? String ?: "Unknown role",
                    isActive = org["isActive"] as? Boolean ?: false,
                    isVerified = org["isVerified"] as? Boolean ?: false
                )
            } else null
    }
}
```

i can't bet that it works 100% correct, but I think I could show the idea.